# Is the comparison in "The Clod and the Pebble" between different types of love?

Tags: poetry, william-blake, songs-of-experience

The poem "The Clod and the Pebble" from William Blake's *Songs of Innocence and Experience* ([which you can read online](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1934/1934-h/1934-h.htm)) is just three verses long and compares two different descriptions of love, attributed to a clod of clay and a pebble respectively. The clod says:

> Love seeketh not itself to please,
>   Nor for itself hath any care,
>   But for another gives its ease,
>   And builds a heaven in hell's despair.

The pebble responds:

> Love seeketh only Self to please,
>   To bind another to its delight,
>   Joys in another's loss of ease,
>   And builds a hell in heaven's despite.

I'd always thought of this poem as describing two different outlooks on love, perhaps by an optimist and a pessimist, or a believer and a cynic, or a youthful lover and a jaded sceptic. I'd assumed that the *love* being described is the same thing both times, except in how different people perceive it.

But in [his answer about a different poem](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/5815/17), Will Crawford analyses "The Clod and the Pebble" as describing two different *types* of love: specifically, in [ancient Greek terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_words_for_love), agápē (love between human and God) and érōs (romantic love). This sounded interesting enough that I'm posting a new question about it to learn more detail.

**What is the evidence that "The Clod and the Pebble" is about two different types of love, rather than two different people's perceptions of love?**

Comment: This is sort of tangential, but I think it's interesting that the clod, which gets stomped on by cattle all day, thinks that love is selfless, whereas the selfish interpretation comes from a pebble that has an easy life (whatever sort of life a pebble has) sitting in the sun by the brook all day.

Comment: @Torisuda I always thought this fit well with my interpretation: the downtrodden clod is willing to sacrifice itself for what it loves, while the privileged pebble is cold and full of disdain.